# Replace the command SQL sum (case) numbers with letters

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Halo mister
I have a program like this.
I want to replace the numbers (in red boxes) with letters, along with the program display:

[image]

The problem:

1. When I replace numbers with letters, a program error occurs
2. When I delete the SUM function, what happens next command is not recognized

I want to replace the program output with letters

[image]

Here is a program that I brief

```
$detail = DB::select('select s.nik, s.nama,
    SUM(CASE
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "01" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Monday" and j.masuk_senin > b.berangkat and j.keluar_senin < b.pulang and j.wf1 = "WFO" THEN "10"
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "01" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Monday" and  j.masuk_senin < b.berangkat and j.keluar_senin < b.pulang and j.wf1 = "WFO" THEN "9"
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "01" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Monday" and
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "01" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Tuesday" and j.masuk_selasa > b.berangkat and j.keluar_selasa < b.pulang and j.wf2 = "WFO" THEN "10"
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "01" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Tuesday" and  j.masuk_selasa < b.berangkat and j.keluar_selasa < b.pulang and j.wf2 = "WFO" THEN "9"
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "01" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Tuesday" and 
    ELSE 0 END ) as h1,

    SUM(CASE
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "02" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Monday" and j.masuk_senin > b.berangkat and j.keluar_senin < b.pulang and j.wf1 = "WFO" THEN "10"
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "02" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Monday" and  j.masuk_senin < b.berangkat and j.keluar_senin < b.pulang and j.wf1 = "WFO" THEN "9"
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "02" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Monday" and
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "02" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Tuesday" and j.masuk_selasa > b.berangkat and j.keluar_selasa < b.pulang and j.wf2 = "WFO" THEN "10"
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "02" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Tuesday" and  j.masuk_selasa < b.berangkat and j.keluar_selasa < b.pulang and j.wf2 = "WFO" THEN "9"
    WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "02" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Tuesday" and 
    ELSE 0 END ) as h2

    from users s
    join tb_presensi b on s.id = b.id_user
    join tb_jammasuk j on s.id = j.id_user
    where b.tanggal between "'.$dari.'" and "'.$sampai.'"
    group by s.id, b.id_user
    order by s.nik ASC');
```

Comment: what is the 'program error' msg? this shouldnt give you query error `WHEN date_format(b.tanggal, "%d") = "01" and DAYNAME(b.tanggal)="Monday" and j.masuk_senin > b.berangkat and j.keluar_senin < b.pulang and j.wf1 = "WFO" THEN "this is ten"`

Comment: I want to display each number with a letter. But when I delete the SUM command the next 'as' is unreadable

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting a program error because the result of your CASE is being inserted into a SUM function.  Someone please correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think you can use SUM on strings.

Comment: Right. But how can I display strings without using SUM?

Because when I don't use SUM the command that I recognize is just the initial 'as' first